# expected difference of maxima

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be random variables for which $X_i \geq Y_i$ a.s. and the $(Y_i)$ are identically distributed. Is it true that
>   \begin{align*}
> E(\max X_i - \max Y_j) \geq E(X_i-Y_i)
> \end{align*}
>   for any $i$?

I tried reducing the problem to a question about the tail probabilities using
\begin{align*}
E(\max X_i - \max Y_j) = \int_0^\infty P(\max X_i - \max Y_i > t) dt,
\end{align*}
since $\max X_i - \max Y_j \geq 0$, but this doesn't appear to directly give the inequality. Can anyone provide a proof or counterexample?

Comment: The tail integral only holds if all the random variables are a.s. positive.

Comment: $X_i \geq Y_i$ for all $i$ should imply that $\max X_i - \max Y_j \geq 0$, no?

Comment: Yes, it does. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X_i - Y_i\geq 0$ for all $i$. You **do** have
$$
\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathbb{E}[X_i - Y_i]
\leq \mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(X_i - Y_i)] \tag{1}
$$
but you **don't** have, in general,
$$
\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathbb{E}[X_i - Y_i]
\leq \mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i - \max_{1\leq i\leq n}Y_i]\tag{2}
$$
To see why (2) can fail to hold, consider $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ i.i.d. Normal $N(0,1)$ r.v.'s, and $X_i=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}Y_j$ for all $i$. Then the RHS of (2) is $0$, but the LHS is
$$
\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq j\leq n} Y_j - Y_i]=
\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq j\leq n} Y_j] - \mathbb{E}[Y_i])
= \max_{1\leq i\leq n}(\mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq j\leq n} Y_j] - 0)
= \mathbb{E}[\max_{1\leq j\leq n} Y_j] \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{2\log n}
$$
which is strictly positive for any not-too-small $n$.